# os.mkdir FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, directory, path, filenotfounderror

I'm trying to create subfolders in an existing directory but mkdir doesn't want to help.

**Code:**

```
import sys
import pickle
import os
import glob
import time
from GenerateEmbeddings import generate_embeddings_narrow, generate_embeddings_wide

input_dir= "Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/input"
output_dir= "Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/output"


input_path_narrow= "Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/input/dataset-narrow"
input_path_wide= "Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/input/dataset-wide"


output_path_narrow= "Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/output/dataset-narrow"
output_path_wide= "Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/output/dataset-wide"

os.mkdir(output_path_narrow)
os.mkdir(output_path_wide)

dataset_narrow= glob.glob(input_path_narrow+'/*.txt')
dataset_wide= glob.glob(input_path_wide+'/*.txt')

try:
    generate_embeddings_narrow(dataset_narrow, input_path_narrow, output_path_narrow)
    del dataset_narrow

    generate_embeddings_wide(dataset_wide, input_path_wide, output_path_wide)
    del dataset_wide

except:
    pass
```

**The Error is:**

```
 File "c:\Users\mohdm\Desktop\Project\Style-Change-Detection-Using-BERT-master\final.py", line 20, in <module>    os.mkdir(output_path_narrow)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/output/dataset-narrow'
```

I pulled the code from: https://github.com/aarish407/Style-Change-Detection-Using-BERT.git

Currently I am using VSCode.

I added a screenshot of the whole screen below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i2uA.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us the file explore you currently have open?

Also, if you use Ctrl + Shift + `, a terminal opens. Can include a screenshot of that too?

Comment: [FileExp](https://imgur.com/a/JHR2iCG)
[Power Shell](https://imgur.com/a/Ed6i625)

Answer (score 0):

first of all try to add "C:/" to the paths,
and try to check that you insterted the correct path
(if they already exist you can get a copy of they're path from your PC folders)

i dont know how you want to set up the upper folders, but if you want to create all the non existing directories in your given path, you'd better using

```
 os.makedirs(*, **)   # create only the last folders in the given path
```

instead of

```
 os.mkdir(*, **)   # create all the folders in the given path
```

if you have to create the upper folders

```
 .../input/...  and
 .../output/...  (or even upper)
```

mkdirs creates all the folders that does not exist in the specified path, instead of just one

Comment: Tired using "C:/" but it doesn't make the difference. Checked the path million times, it's correct. Tried ".../input/..." too but same error. 
idk what's wrong with this. Also yes, I'm in a venv.

Comment: like @Chase C says try to use relative imports

Comment: if you are running script.py from Project folder try use simply os.mkdir("input/dataset-narrow")

Comment: @CatchTwentyTwo did you also try to use `os.makedirs` instead of `os.mkdir`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are not running the Python file from the right spot, so when you call os.mkdir it isn't recognizing the path. If you try just calling

```py
os.mkdir("./dataset-narrow")
```

instead of the longer path you are given, that might fix it.

I am betting that the path `Users/mohdm/Desktop/Project/input/` does not exist in your current working directory, so instead use relative paths.

Comment: Still no changes. the path is correct. Added a ss below
[image](https://imgur.com/a/JHR2iCG)

Comment: Hm. Okay. Could you try `input_path_narrow= "C:\\Users\\mohdm\\Desktop\\Project\\input\\dataset-narrow"? Also, it would be helpful for you if you were able to copy the directory from the top of the file explorer.